# Setting local config in SQL before INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, row-level-security, postgraphile

newbie in SQL coming from a JS world needing some advice on triggers.
My user has an `id` column and my GraphQL API always calls `INSERT INTO .... RETURNING *` and then doing the transforms on the GraphQL layer to return what I want.
The goal is to allow a query like `INSERT INTO .... RETURNING *` work with RLS in place.

The policies are:

```sql
CREATE POLICY USER_SELECT_RESTRICTIONS 
ON "user" 
FOR SELECT
USING ("id" = current_user_id() OR current_user_role() = 'admin' OR current_user_role() = 'partner');

CREATE POLICY USER_INSERT_RESTRICTIONS
ON "user" 
FOR INSERT
WITH CHECK (true);
```

This breaks for guest users (more context at the bottom) because they are allowed to `INSERT` but cannot `SELECT` (because of the restriction that only authorized users can select their own rows).

So I had the idea to somehow set the user setting manually in a trigger before/after insert (don't know which because I couldn't move forward due to the syntax error).

I've tried this but I get a syntax error at the `NEW.id`? (it just says "Syntax Error" to me)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_user_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  SET LOCAL jwt.claims.userId NEW.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_user_id_on_insert
AFTER INSERT ON "user"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_user_insert();
```

Searched around a lot and to be honest I think I may just not find anything because I am missing the correct terminology to find what I need to find.

Would appreciate not only help on what on this specific problem but also any related advice on policies for guest users that need priviliges.

Context:

These are the relevant tables and functions

```sql
CREATE TYPE "user_role" AS ENUM (
  'customer',
  'partner',
  'admin'
);
​
CREATE TABLE "user" (
  "id" uuid UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  "first_name" varchar NOT NULL,
  "last_name" varchar NOT NULL,
  "email" text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  "role" user_role NOT NULL DEFAULT 'customer',
  "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
​
CREATE FUNCTION current_user_id() RETURNS uuid AS $$
  SELECT nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.userId', true), '')::uuid;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL stable;
​
CREATE FUNCTION current_user_role() RETURNS user_role AS $$
  SELECT nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.role', true), '')::user_role;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL stable
```

The RLS restricts `SELECT` to rows where the `id` column of the `user` table matches `current_setting('jwt.claims.userId')`.
This was set previously by Postgraphile as seen here (https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/security/).

One possible workaround I thought of would be this but I don't know if this would lead to some kind of vulnerabilities because of the obvious role elevation:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION after_user_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  SET LOCAL jwt.claims.role TO "customer";
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_user_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  SET LOCAL jwt.claims.role TO "admin";
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON "user"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_user_insert();

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert
AFTER INSERT ON "user"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE after_user_insert();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your don't say what a guest is, but your approach seems wrong.

Rather than disabling your checks on a low level, which gives you a bad feeling for good reasons, you should choose one of the following approaches:

- fix your policies to allow the necessary operation (perhaps by adding a permissive policy)
- have certain operations performed by a `SECURITY DEFINER` function that belongs to a user not subject to the restrictions.

If you insist on a trigger based solution, you have to use a `BEFORE` trigger. Also, consider that you cannot use parameterss with a `SET` statement. You'd either have to use dynamic SQL or (better) use a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_user_insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$BEGIN
   SELECT set_config('jwt.claims.userId', NEW.id::text, TRUE);
   RETURN NEW;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_user_id_on_insert BEFORE INSERT ON "user"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE before_user_insert();
```

Comment: A guest is any invoker of my API that doesn't have a role or a user_id set in their authorization headers.  
I don't see a way to modify my policies to allow an INSERT followed up by returning exactly the row inserted right now AND restrict access to only the rows the user owns. 

The `SECURITY DEFINER` seems like the way I did it before: Only allowing `INSERT`s through my own function which is, I guess, ok. But not the gist of "updating the security context within a trigger so the followup `RETURNING *` works

Comment: A advise against your idea with a trigger. I guess I must me missing something, but I don't see why you don't define a permissive `INSERT` policy for guests.

Comment: It's not the `INSERT` as an issue here but the `RETURNING *` afterwards which makes me to have some kind of `SELECT` policy for guest users. The `INSERT` goes through completely fine without any kind of triggers but when doing a `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING *` it doesn't work. I cannot not do it a different way because that is the way Postgraphile (the API layer I use ontop) does it and migrating away from it because of that is too much of an architectural cost.

Comment: I have extended the answer to give you a hint for the trigger function.

Comment: Oh wow, I was missing the type on the `NEW.id`. That makes it clearer that I need to provide that. Thanks for the help, that was the missing piece in my syntax. (Apart from using the `BEFORE` trigger)